# Change registry DisableTaskManager not working in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, registry

I want to disable a standard user from accessing the task manager. With `gpedit.msc` this works without problems, but I need to do this from the Windows registry. I already tried assigning 1 to the key `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System\DiableTaskMgr`, but it is not working.

I use a bat file:

`REG ADD "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System" /v DisableTaskMgr /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f
REG ADD "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System" /v DisableChangePassword /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f
taskkill /IM explorer.exe /F`

Comment: The correct way to do this is to use group policy.

Comment: But the user does not have gpedit or regedit or shell windows, just an application buttons to disable and enable these features, buttons execute a bat file. 
For security reasons we do not want users to run applications other than those that provide Our ​​Fan, this in Windows XP worked without problems.
Thanks anyway.